# Determine missing (required) fields in Protobuf .NET

Tags: protobuf-net

I want to make sure a protobuf object is valid (all required fields are provided) before I try to send it to the server. The protobuf .NET serializer is not strict enough to tell me this - what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I hope to strengthen in v2, basically be injecting an exception into the logic that decides *not* to write a specific field. For now you would need to verify externally. I'll go and log a work-item for this.

Comment: has this item been addressed in the subsequent release of protobuf v2? http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=143 I guess not seeing as the issue is still open :)

Comment: @edward c2 is still very much in active development. I do not think I've addressed that, but I'll get to it!

Comment: Is this something that's now been addressed in v2?

Comment: @NiallConnaughton nope, nothing built in for that yet; the optional vs required kinda works differently in the case of model-first, so that mainly controls what assumptions / checks the library makes; it *could* do more, but right now: it doesn't

Comment: @MarcGravell  How to verify this externally for basic data types? Optional fields could be verified externally with *ShouldSerialize()* methods. But required fields doesn't have that option. We could check for null on references. But not on value types.